# Perl - Remove CSS (and other unwanted characters) from text files

Tags: html, css, perl

I am using the following code to strip html elements off txt files in a directory:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;
use HTML::FormatText;
 use Cwd;

my $direct = "/directory/";

opendir my $dh, $direct or die "Can't open directory";

while ( readdir $dh ) {

  next if /^\./;

  my $file = File::Spec->catfile($direct, $_);
  print $file."\n";
  my $outfile = File::Spec->catfile($direct, "out_$_");
  next unless -f $file;

  my $html = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq(Unable to open "$file" for reading: $!);
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
  };

  next unless $html =~ /<html/i;

  my $formatted = HTML::FormatText->format_string(
      $html, leftmargin => 0, rightmargin => 60);

  open my $fh, '>', $outfile or die qq(Unable to open "$outfile" for writing: $!);

  print $fh "File: $file\n\n";
  print $fh "$formatted\n";
  print $fh "*" x 40, "\n" ;

  close $fh or die qq(Unable to close "$outfile" after writing: $!);
   unlink $file or warn "Could not unlink $file: $!";
}
```

But it seems like many unwanted characters are left in the resulting output:

```
&lt;div style="text-align:center;"&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;margin-left:0px;"&gt;TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style="text-align:center;"&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;margin-left:0px;"&gt;TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style="text-align:center;"&gt;&amp;#160;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;p style='margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt'&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;margin-left:0px;"&gt;1&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;"&gt;.  &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;"&gt;ORGANIZATION &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;"&gt;AND&lt;/font&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;"&gt; SUMMARY OF &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;"&gt;SIGNIFICANT ACCOUNTING &lt;/font&gt;&lt;font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;text-
```

Any idea how to get rid of these HTML/CSS? (But keep the text that is inside these tags) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML::Parser distribution contains [an example program](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.71/eg/htext) that extracts the plain text from an HTML file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Extract all plain text from an HTML file

use strict;
use HTML::Parser 3.00 ();

my %inside;

sub tag
{
   my($tag, $num) = @_;
   $inside{$tag} += $num;
   print " ";  # not for all tags
}

sub text
{
    return if $inside{script} || $inside{style};
    print $_[0];
}

HTML::Parser->new(api_version => 3,
          handlers    => [start => [\&tag, "tagname, '+1'"],
                  end   => [\&tag, "tagname, '-1'"],
                  text  => [\&text, "dtext"],
                 ],
          marked_sections => 1,
    )->parse_file(shift) || die "Can't open file: $!\n";
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how I can use that.. Can you please give me an example on how to use this on all files of the directory that I refer to in my initial post ? ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious) installed then something like:

```
perl -MMojo::DOM -0 -e 'print my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(<>)->all_text()' file.html
```

will likely work :-)

**Explainer:**  `Mojo::DOM->new(<>)->all_text()`  should be self explanatory ;-) ... the `<>` just makes a DOM object out of what you feed it on `STDIN`  and `->all_text()` runs the `all_text` method on that object.

See [`perlun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for the `-0` switch. Essentially it is for slurping the file so that `<>` contains the whole thing (errm ... someone will correct me in comments) . You can make a real script with [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) more like Dave's answer instead of just a hackish oneliner as in my example.